# How to add Name field in Docusing envelope?

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

Currently i can create envelope with signers dynamically, now i want to add Name field above the signer,  i using below code to set Auto search Text.

```
         ' Document
 Dim doc1 As Document = New Document With {
        .DocumentBase64 = doc1DocxBytes,
        .Name = ext1(0),
        .FileExtension = ext1(1),
        .DocumentId = "1"
    }
    
    env.Documents = New List(Of Document) From {
           doc1
    }
    
    'Signer1
    Dim signer1 As Signer = New Signer With {
        .Email = signerEmail,
        .Name = signerName,
        .RecipientId = "1",
        .RoutingOrder = "1"
    }
    
     Dim signHere212 As SignHere = New SignHere With {
        .AnchorString = "For and on behalf of the vendor",
        .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        .AnchorYOffset = "70",
        .AnchorXOffset = "20"
    }
    
      Dim fullName212 As FullName = New FullName With {
    .AnchorString = "For and on behalf of the vendor",
    .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    .AnchorYOffset = "100",
    .AnchorXOffset = "20"
}


     Dim signer1Tabs As Tabs = New Tabs With {
        .SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere) From {
           signHere212
          },
       .FullNameTabs = New List(Of FullName) From {
        fullName212
   }
   }
   
   signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs
   
   
   Dim recipients As Recipients = New Recipients With {
        .Signers = New List(Of Signer) From {
            signer1
            }
    }
    
     env.Recipients = recipients
        env.Status = "sent"
        
             Dim envelopeEvents = New List(Of EnvelopeEvent)()
        envelopeEvents.Add(New EnvelopeEvent With {
        .EnvelopeEventStatusCode = "completed",
        .IncludeDocuments = "true"
    })
        eventNotification.EnvelopeEvents = envelope
```

From above code i placed sign on the top of "For and on behalf of the vendor", now i want Name field to add Name when signer sign the document.Please provide piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim fullName212 As FullName = New FullName With {
            .AnchorString = "For and on behalf of the vendor",
            .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
            .AnchorYOffset = "70",
            .AnchorXOffset = "20"
        }

 Dim signer1Tabs As Tabs = New Tabs With {
        .SignHereTabs = New List(Of SignHere) From {
            signHere1
                  },

        .FullNameTabs = New List(Of FullName) From {
            fullName212
    }
  signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs

     Dim recipients As Recipients = New Recipients With {
        .Signers = New List(Of Signer) From {
            signer1
        }
    }
```

Comment: but how to add that FullName object in envelope, above i updated how signer object call in envelope Recipients.

Comment: Thanks for reply, still i am not getting name when signer sign the document, form ur code where to specify Name value ?  here i passed email and name  Dim signer1 As Signer = New Signer With {
        .Email = signerEmail,
        .Name = signerName,
        .RecipientId = "1",
        .RoutingOrder = "1"
    }  but still not getting name.

Comment: you cannot specify the name, it's the name of the DocuSign user, it's done automatically. If you want to be able to specify a name in your code - you will need a text tab, not a name tab.

Comment: Yes how to add next tab for Name field Ss-http://prntscr.com/1066twe ,pls provide adding name tab codes, I want Name stamp when click user sign stamp

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand

Comment: or how to populate Name value once open document by signer, i need to place the position where it will appear, i checked manually create envelope with disgner and drag and drop Name field ,so once signer open doc , it will appear that singer name.I want like that.Better pls provide any document (C#) if got for populate all other standard fields Ss -http://prntscr.com/1068211

Comment: I provided code to add name tab. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: this code above does exactly this, it adds a name tab in a specific X/Y position.

Comment: Hi, i updated full code for signer1, form that i will get only signature stamp, and not getting Name of the signer.Pls check this Ss - http://prntscr.com/1068i13, i want like this, that one i create template and pass doc in docusign web.

Comment: the name tab does not require user interaction, it just will put the name, without giving you something to click on.

Comment: yes correct, using above code name will not appear, and same time if i pass doc in docusing web, when signer 1 open the doc, name will appear,, is anything missing in my above code ?

Comment: The code above creates an envelope with name tab. How do you use it later? do you create a view for embedded signing? do you use a template? that could be part of the problem. Please provide full exact code you are running that you say is not working.

Comment: yes i updated full code for signer1, i am creating envelope via code and used Auto Place to sign the doc, i never use template.

Comment: AutoPlace with an anchor tag? that may be the issue. Is the text "For and on behalf of the vendor" shows in the document?

Comment: yes, AutoPlace with  anchor tag which i specify x and y coordinates to appear signature stamp, and "For and on behalf of the vendor" this line in our pdf document.By default name field not appear above the signature stamp ?

Comment: no, it does not, there's no such feature, you have to specify it yourself.

Comment: could u provide code in vb or C# for specify name field ?

Comment: I did, that's my answer above.

Comment: hi i specify signature tab and full name tab , but only signature will appear, here the code, i just increase position of full name tab, but still not working.
 Dim signHere212 As SignHere = New SignHere With {
        .AnchorString = "For and on behalf of the vendor",
        .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        .AnchorYOffset = "70",
        .AnchorXOffset = "20"
    }
    
      Dim fullName212 As FullName = New FullName With {
    .AnchorString = "For and on behalf of the vendor",
    .AnchorUnits = "pixels",
    .AnchorYOffset = "100",
    .AnchorXOffset = "20"
}

Comment: try to not use anchor strings but fixed position and see if you see them then?